# How to add subsubsection without affecting the default styling of "Chapter"

Tags: sectioning

I am using the following code for numbering the `subsubsection` and also to have the fontsize same as that of the `subsection`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

% ----------------To add \subsubsection -------------------
\usepackage{sectsty}
\subsubsectionfont{\fontsize{12}{15}\selectfont}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
% ---------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}

\end{document}
```

This is affecting the spacing between the number of the chapter and the name of the chapter as seen in the attached images. How can this be avoided?

`subsubsection` without the numbering and the default font size:

[image]

`subsubsection` with the numbering and custom font size:

[image]

Comment: Would you please provide a compilable MWE. How can we know what you do exactly where in your preamble?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\addtokomafont{subsubsection}{\fontsize{12}{15}\selectfont}` instead of `sectsty`

The KOMA-Script classes have their own commands to customize section titles.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

% ----------------To add \subsubsection -------------------
%\usepackage{sectsty}
%\subsubsectionfont{\fontsize{12}{15}\selectfont}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
% ---------------------------------------------------------

\addtokomafont{subsubsection}{\fontsize{12}{15}\selectfont} % <<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\begin{document}
    
    \chapter{Chapter}
    \section{Section}
    \subsection{Subsection}
    \subsubsection{Subsubsection}
    
\end{document}
```